# How to find the snap package which is published in private mode

Tags: 16.04, snap, ubuntu-store

I was uploaded a snap package on last week, after the review i am getting published status from Ubuntu store. Now i need to install that package,i was searched in $ snap find and Ubuntu store but i didn't get.

How to find the snap package which is published in private mode.
Please any one give suggestion..

Comment: “published in private” sounds awfully oxymoronic…